# How can I use localized assets with angular localize

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular-localize

I would like to use Angular localize ([@angular/localize](https://angular.io/api/localize)) in one of my Angular projects. Translating texts into different languages was straightforward with the help of the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview). However, I also have a few localized images, and I can't figure out how to handle those.

If I target two languages, let's say English (en) and German (de), then I have one image per language, for example `my-image_en.png` and `my-image_de.png`. The first should show up on the English site, and the second on the German site.

When building my project, a separate folder is generated per language:

```
- /dist
    - /my-site
        - /en
            - /assets
                - my-image.png
            - index.html
            - ...
        - /de
            - /assets
                - my-image.png
            - index.html
            - ...
```

each of which has its own assets folder. It seems logical that there is a way to get `my-image_en.png` in `dist/my-site/en/assets` and `my-image_de.png` in `dist/my-site/de/assets`, but I can't find anything about that in the documentation, nor when I search for that on the internet.

Does anyone know if this can be achieved with Angular localize? Or is this something I need to configure in the `angular.json` file?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't solve it. It was for a small trial project only, where localization wasn't essential. I was only curious if there is a solution for this issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My problem which I thought initially related to this turned out to be a missing image file left out of my publish pipeline. (facepalm)